How to change the number of rows per page
I'm beginner to Flutter.
I want to display a table with three columns. But I don't know how to change the number of rows per page. Maybe I should override onRowsPerPageChanged, but I don't know how.
Sorry for my bad english.
My code:
class PaginatedDataTableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaginatedDataTableExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(label: Text(
                'id',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            ),),
            DataColumn(label: Text(
                'Begin',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            ),),
            DataColumn(label: Text(
                'End',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            ),),
          ],
          source: DataTableSourceExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


you can use rowsPerPage: 3  in PaginatedDataTable.

Yes you need to use the onRowsPerPageChanged property. This property expects a callback function that will be called when the user changes the number of rows per page.
see example:
class PaginatedDataTableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginatedDataTableExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PaginatedDataTableExampleState createState() =>
      _PaginatedDataTableExampleState();
}

class _PaginatedDataTableExampleState extends State<PaginatedDataTableExample> {
  int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
  final List<int> _rowsPerPageOptions = [5, 10, 20];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
          onRowsPerPageChanged: (newRowsPerPage) {
            setState(() {
              _rowsPerPage = newRowsPerPage!;
            });
          },
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'id',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'Begin',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'End',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          source: DataTableSourceExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

